# Javascript websockets closing immediately after opening

Tags: javascript, websocket, go

```
connection = new WebSocket("ws://localhost:1050/join?username=test")

connection.onopen = function(){
   alert('Connection open!');
}


connection.onmessage = function(e){
   var server_message = e.data;
   alert(server_message);
}

connection.onclose = function() {
    alert("websocket closing")
}
```

The connection to the server is established and an alert is displayed for Connection open! However immediately afterwards the connection closes. The server does not call close and there seem to be no other errors in the console. This is happening in both chrome and firefox.

I looked at a bunch of different similar examples on the web but to no avail.

Comment: the problem might be in your server code, can you post it?

Comment: If you use `code.google.com/p/go.net/websocket`, the connection will close as soon as the handler function exits. That is by design and will not give any error. Maybe that might be the problem?

Comment: I am using that. 

Is there any way to avoid that from happening, or is it inherently part of the library design which we can't work around?

Comment: I'm using express-ws, WebSocket endpoints for Express applications. I ran into the same problem server side while trying to bypass the app route and simply use wss.on('connection'). Once I opened up an app route with app.ws('/ws') then the websocket connection maintained.

Answer (score -8, accepted):

Fixed it!

All I had to do was block the handler from returning before the websocket connection closes

Comment: Mark your answer as accepted. This is perfectly okay.

Comment: Could you elaborate please? I'm having the same problem now. What do you mean by handler return?

Comment: I dont understand what you mean with this...could you please provide some detailed information on what you did?

Comment: really what do you mean by returning handler before closing connection?

Comment: Same boat, what does "block the handler from returning" mean?

Comment: Elaborate your answer, many of us are having the same issue.  What code change did you make?

Comment: This answer helped me address a similar issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37211037/wildfly-websocket-apache-websocket-is-already-in-closing-or-closed-state/#37785464

Answer (score 12):

to Keep Websocket Opened prevent handler from returning by `return false;` in `connection.onmessage`
like this :

```
connection.onmessage = function(e){
   var server_message = e.data;
   alert(server_message);
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 9):

I believe I've stumbled across the solution that OP found but failed miserably to explain. I don't have enough reputation to comment, otherwise I'd be responding to all of the confused comments begging for clarification on OP's response.

The short version is that I think OP was referring to his *server-side connection handler* when he said "All I had to do was block the handler from returning before the websocket connection closes".

It turns out my server was closing the webSocket automatically because I didn't understand how a certain webSocket function worked. Specifically, I was using a Python server script with asyncio/websockets and the following code:

```
async def receiveCommandsLoop(player):
    while True:
        msg = await player.websocket.recv()
        print(command)

async def handleClient(websocket, path):
    username = await websocket.recv()
    player = players[username]

    ...

    #Start task to listen for commands from player
    asyncio.get_event_loop().create_task(receiveCommandsLoop(player))

start_server = websockets.serve(handleClient, '', 8765)
```

The idea was that websockets.serve would use handleClient to begin the connection and do some setup, then create a new task with receiveCommandsLoop that would take over the job of communication.

But it turns out: when you call websockets.serve, Python expects that when your handler (in this case, handleClient) returns, you must be done with the socket, and it closes it automatically.

Thus, by the time receiveCommandsLoop was run, handleClient had returned, and the webSocket had been automatically closed.

I was able to fix this by simply modifying my handleClient function to directly run the loop originally contained in receiveCommandsLoop. Hope this helps someone out there.

Answer (score 1):

Piecing together hints from this post and others, I found a solution that works when using the python websocket server example found everywhere that includes something like:

```
async def handler(websocket, path):
    data = await websocket.recv()
    reply = f"Data recieved as: {data}!"
    await websocket.send(reply)
```

To those of us new to websocket, I think the assumption is that the `handler` function will be called each time the client sends a message, which turns out not to be the case. As others mention, the connection closes as soon as the handler function returns once. The solution I found is to change it to:

```
async def handler(websocket, path):
    async for data in websocket:
        reply = f"Data recieved as: {data}!"
        print(data)
        await websocket.send(reply)
```

My client-side javascript code is equivalent to the OP's and I didn't have to change anything for this to work.

Unfortunately I can't explain why `async for data in websocket:` makes it actually wait forever and spontaneously run the inner code block each time a message is received, but it does for me and I get all the expected log messages both on the python server side and the client javascript console.

If anyone more knowledgeable on this topic can comment on whether this is a good-for-general-use solution or if there's a gotcha to look out for here, it would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This also could be the case when you're trying to send binary data over a websocket connection, but some side (client or server) is trying to interpret it as a text - many libraries and frameworks do it unless you explicitly specify you do want binary data.

Answer (score 0):

It could also be a login problem. The websocket will automatically close the website required authentication but no authentication information was provided.